# Android: Creating Formatted Native Android Application that takes Web Content

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I'm trying to code a native android application that takes certain parts of a webpage and displays it. Basically I would want a search bar and several other things, so that I can have a clean fitted display on a mobile device. It is the same idea as the Facebook application, I am trying to create a stripped down version of a webpage.

I know how to download a full webpage using a WebView, but how can I take only certain parts of that webpage and display that instead?

EDIT: Is there any way to do this using just java and java-based api's?

(I am writing the application in native JAVA)

Best,
Aneem

Comment: Did you refer jquery mobile framework?

Comment: I don't really know JavaScript, so I was hoping to avoid that. Though it seems like I might just have to learn it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not sure from your question if your back-end has web api's implemented via REST, SOAP, whatever. If it does then you'd just use the necessary pieces widgets and all to implement your android application.

If it doesn't then there may not be a direct way to implement what you want. So I'd suggest looking into the back end first before looking at this aspect.

However, you might want to look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) if you want to implement a cross platform solution.

Comment: I'm not using any other api's, I was hoping to be able to do it all using just the android frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you effectively want to do 'web-scraping'.

I've done this by using an `HTTPClient` to pull a web-page which I then processed with [HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to produce an XML document. I could then drill down through it to extract the various elements I needed (tables mostly).

You'll need to reverse-engineer the web page using the 'view source' capabilities of a web browser.

Be aware though that unless you have total control of the web page source, web-scraping is generally not a great way of producing a stable and extensible app. All it takes is for a re-design of the web page by whoever maintains it and it will potentially break your app completely forcing you to rewrite your HTML processing code.

**EDIT**: Actually, on the subject of the Facebook app - this isn't the same thing. There are published APIs for accessing Facebook which don't involve accessing the normal Facebook pages. The Facebook app is a 'native' Android app not a web app.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way I can build something like a native android app though? For example, can I have a WebView with just a searchbar, and when the user inputs a token, I can send the token to the website and retrieve a table? If so, how can I go about doing this? (I've changed the phrasing of the question as well, I was a bit confused before)

Comment: IF you're asking if it's possible to download selected (individual) parts of a web page then the answer is no that's not how things work with basic HTTP and HTML. As Manish mentions in his answer, if the web site has back-end (server-side) web services, then providing the correct call into those services may return specific results but this sort of stuff is all site-specific and there is no single way that all sites behave.